# what would be the best way to work out the limit of a recursive sequence an+1 = sqrt(an) ; a1= 1/2

Tags: real-analysis

There is a result that says that, *if* a sequence $a_n$ tends to a limit $L,$ then $a_{n+1}$ also tends to $L.$ In this instance, this gives an equation for $L.$ But am unsure of how to derive this equation from this recursive sequence

Comment: Is the title supposed to say $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n};\ a_1=\frac12?$  You should format your posts with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) sol they'll be easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to show that the sequence converges, try this:
Let $x^*$ be the limit of the sequence.
Then you have
$$
x^*
= \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n
= \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n + 1}
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{x_n}
\overset{(\star)}{=} \sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n}
= \sqrt{x^*}.
$$
Where $(\star)$ uses the continuity of the square root.
Then you arrive at @Peter Foreman's answer

Answer (score 1):

To show that the sequence converges:

If
$a_{n+1}
=\sqrt{a_n}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
a_{n+1}-1
&=\sqrt{a_n}-1\\
&=(\sqrt{a_n}-1)\dfrac{\sqrt{a_n}+1}{\sqrt{a_n}+1}\\
&=\dfrac{a_n-1}{\sqrt{a_n}+1}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{a_{n+1}-1}{a_{n}-1}
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a_n}+1}\\
\text{so}\\
\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}-1}{a_{n}-1}\right|
&=\dfrac{1}{|\sqrt{a_n}+1|}\\
&\lt 1\\
\end{array}
$

If $a_1 > 1$,
then
$a_n > 1$ for all $n$
so
$\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}-1}{a_{n}-1}\right|
=\dfrac{1}{|\sqrt{a_n}+1|}
\lt \dfrac12
$;
if $0 < a_1 < 1$,
then
$a_n \ge a_1$ for all $n$
so
$\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}-1}{a_{n}-1}\right|
=\dfrac{1}{|\sqrt{a_1}+1|}
\lt \dfrac1{a_1+1}
$.

In either case,
$|a_n-1|
\to 0
$
geometrically.

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\sqrt{L}$$
$$L^2-L=0$$
$$L(L-1)=0$$
$$L=0,1$$
But $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$ as the sequence is strictly increasing and starts at $\frac12$.

Comment: thank you! very helpful!

Comment: @HarshKumar Do you want to give me an upvote or accept my answer then?

Comment: new user, hence upvote doesn't show.